# Display posts from multiple facebook feed using JSON

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, facebook

I want to create a script (javascript/jQuery) for a WordPress website which allow me to have latest posts from multiple Facebook pages. I don't want the posts to be ordered by account, but be mixed all together, ordered by created_time. I've already search for plugin, I don't want a WP plugin.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <title>FaceBook Posts</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    function fbFetch(){
        //Set Url of JSON data from the facebook graph api. make sure callback is set with a '?' to overcome the cross domain problems with JSON
        var url = "https://graph.facebook.com/footengo31/posts?access_token=XXX&limit=5&callback=?";
        var url2 = "https://graph.facebook.com/footengo01/posts?access_token=XXX&limit=5&callback=?";
        var url3 = "https://graph.facebook.com/Footengo69/posts?access_token=XXX&limit=5&callback=?";

        $.getJSON(url,function(json1){

            $.getJSON(url2,function(json2){

                $.getJSON(url3,function(json3){

                    var json = {};
                    json['json1'] = json1;
                    json['json2'] = json2;
                    json['json3'] = json3;

                    var json_array = [];


                    json_array.push(json);

                    //Use jQuery getJSON method to fetch the data from the url and then create our unordered list with the relevant data.
                        var html = "<ul>";
                            //loop through and within data array's retrieve the message variable.
                            $.each(json.json1.data, function(i,fb){
                                if (typeof fb.picture != "undefined") {
                                    html += "<li>" + fb.message + "</br>" + '<img SRC="' + fb.picture + '">' + "</br>" + fb.created_time + "</li></br>";
                                }
                                else{
                                    html += "<li>" + fb.message + "</br>" + fb.created_time + "</li></br>";
                                }
                            });

                            $.each(json.json2.data,function(i,fb){
                                if (typeof fb.picture != "undefined") {
                                    html += "<li>" + fb.message + "</br>" + '<img SRC="' + fb.picture + '">' + "</br>" + fb.created_time + "</li></br>";
                                }
                                else{
                                    html += "<li>" + fb.message + "</br>" + fb.created_time + "</li></br>";
                                }
                            });

                            $.each(json.json3.data,function(i,fb){
                                if (typeof fb.picture != "undefined") {
                                    html += "<li>" + fb.message + "</br>" + '<img SRC="' + fb.picture + '">' + "</br>" + fb.created_time + "</li></br>";
                                }
                                else{
                                    html += "<li>" + fb.message + "</br>" + fb.created_time + "</li></br>";
                                }
                            });

                        html += "</ul>";
                        //A little animation once fetched
                        $('.facebookfeed').animate({opacity:0}, 500, function(){
                            $('.facebookfeed').html(html);
                        });

                        $('.facebookfeed').animate({opacity:1}, 500);

                });
            });
        });

    };




    </script>

</head>


<body onload="fbFetch();">
    <div class="facebookfeed">Loading...</div>

</body>
```

I have 5 last posts for my 3 account, but 5 lasts from the first page, 5 last posts from the second one ... That give me this result:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with one request instead of three:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=footengo31,footengo01,Footengo69&fields=posts.limit(5){message,created_time,picture}&access_token={your_access_token}
```

returns

```
   {
    "footengo31": {
        "posts": {
            "data": [
                {
                    "message": "Vu sur Football65 - Le président de GUIZERIX met les choses au point...    http://www.foot31.fr/Vu-sur-Football65-Le-president-de-GUIZERIX-met-les-choses-au-point_a11672.html",
                    "created_time": "2015-09-04T07:04:07+0000",
                    "id": "298593320199_10154353705475200"
                },
                {
                    "message": "DH - Comment l'AS MURET a changé de style... http://www.foot31.fr/DH-Comment-l-AS-MURET-a-change-de-style_a11670.html",
                    "created_time": "2015-09-04T07:03:46+0000",
                    "id": "298593320199_10154353703060200"
                },
                {
                    "message": "CFA - Nouveau départ, nouveau cycle pour le RODEZ AF ?",
                    "created_time": "2015-09-04T06:59:51+0000",
                    "id": "298593320199_10154353697905200"
                },
                {
                    "message": "Coupe de France - Le tirage du 3ème tour est en ligne... http://www.foot31.fr/Coupe-de-France-tirage-du-3eme-tour-ONET-LE-CHATEAU-et-SAINT-ALBAN-deja-qualifies-_a11668.html",
                    "created_time": "2015-09-03T07:57:36+0000",
                    "id": "298593320199_10154351103020200"
                },
                {
                    "message": "DH féminines - Nicolas CASTANIER (TFC) : \"Reveniraveclesfillesétaitinévitable...\" http://www.foot31.fr/DH-feminines-Nicolas-CASTANIER-TFC-Revenir-avec-les-filles-etait-inevitable_a11660.html",
                    "created_time": "2015-09-03T07:49:52+0000",
                    "id": "298593320199_10154351087560200"
                }
            ],
            "paging": {
                "previous": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/298593320199/posts?limit=5&fields=message,created_time&since=1441350247&access_token=&__paging_token=&__previous=1",
                "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/298593320199/posts?limit=5&fields=message,created_time&access_token=&until=1441266592&__paging_token="
            }
        },
        "id": "298593320199"
    },
    "footengo01": {
        "posts": {
            "data": [
                {
                    "message": "PHR (A et D) - Confirmations attendues pour PORTES DE L'AIN et DOMBES BRESSE, FEILLENS va savoir http://www.football01.fr/PHR-A-et-D-Confirmations-attendues-pour-PORTES-DE-L-AIN-et-DOMBES-BRESSE-FEILLENS-va-savoir_a5534.html",
                    "created_time": "2015-09-04T06:47:31+0000",
                    "id": "174766979959_10150544890344960"
                },
                {
                    "message": "Quelques réactions en vidéo après le tirage au sort du troisième tour http://www.footengo69.fr/Coupe-de-France-Les-reactions-apres-le-tirage-au-sort_a12605.html",
                    "created_time": "2015-09-02T20:07:32+0000",
                    "id": "174766979959_10150544489819960"
                },
                {
                    "message": "Le tirage et l'analyse du troisième tour de la coupe de France http://www.footengo69.fr/Coupe-de-France-Des-affiches-pour-le-troisieme-tour_a12604.html",
                    "created_time": "2015-09-02T19:46:19+0000",
                    "id": "174766979959_10150544484489960"
                },
                {
                    "message": "Le tirage complet, c'est ici et seulement ici Une réaction ? Déçu ? Heureux ? Mitigé ? On vous donne rendez-vous un peu plus tard pour les analyses et les réactions des intéressés. http://www.footengo69.fr/Coupe-de-France-Le-tirage-du-troisieme-tour-est-en-ligne_a12603.html",
                    "created_time": "2015-09-02T17:41:22+0000",
                    "id": "174766979959_10150544441624960"
                },
                {
                    "message": "Ce soir, le tirage du troisième tour de la coupe de France aura lieu à 18h30 au Siège de la Ligue Rhône-Alpes. Il marque l'entrée en lice des formations de CFA2, d'Honneur et de HR. Rendez-vous à 18h20 pour suivre en direct ce rendez-vous incontournable sur nos sites depuis plusieurs années. http://www.footengo69.fr/Coupe-de-France-Suivez-le-tirage-au-sort-du-troisieme-tour-EN-DIRECT-des-18h30_a12603.html",
                    "created_time": "2015-09-02T10:18:44+0000",
                    "id": "174766979959_10150544343284960"
                }
            ],
            "paging": {
                "previous": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/174766979959/posts?limit=5&fields=message,created_time&since=1441349251&access_token=&__paging_token=&__previous=1",
                "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/174766979959/posts?limit=5&fields=message,created_time&access_token=&until=1441189124&__paging_token="
            }
        },
        "id": "174766979959"
    },
    "Footengo69": {
        "posts": {
            "data": [
                {
                    "message": "Présentation de la PHR poule B et F... http://www.footengo69.fr/PHR-Poule-B-et-F-Cinq-RHODANIENS-prets-au-combat_a12607.html",
                    "created_time": "2015-09-04T09:11:17+0000",
                    "id": "283981085258_10153512214115259"
                },
                {
                    "message": "Quelques réactions en vidéo après le tirage au sort du troisième tour http://www.footengo69.fr/Coupe-de-France-Les-reactions-apres-le-tirage-au-sort_a12605.html",
                    "created_time": "2015-09-02T20:05:35+0000",
                    "id": "283981085258_10153508723965259"
                },
                {
                    "message": "Analyse du tirage du 3ème tour de la coupe de France",
                    "created_time": "2015-09-02T19:32:02+0000",
                    "id": "283981085258_10153508588080259"
                },
                {
                    "message": "Le tirage complet, c'est ici et seulement ici Une réaction ? Déçu ? Heureux ? Mitigé ? http://www.footengo69.fr/Coupe-de-France-Le-tirage-du-troisieme-tour-est-en-ligne_a12603.html",
                    "created_time": "2015-09-02T17:38:43+0000",
                    "id": "283981085258_10153508422120259"
                },
                {
                    "message": "C'est parti http://www.footengo69.fr/Coupe-de-France-Le-tirage-du-troisieme-tour-va-commencer_a12603.html",
                    "created_time": "2015-09-02T16:46:08+0000",
                    "id": "283981085258_10153508218775259"
                }
            ],
            "paging": {
                "previous": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/283981085258/posts?limit=5&fields=message,created_time&since=1441357877&access_token=&__paging_token=&__previous=1",
                "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/283981085258/posts?limit=5&fields=message,created_time&access_token=&until=1441212368&__paging_token="
            }
        },
        "id": "283981085258"
    }
}
```

The complete logic would be

```
function fbFetch(){

    var url = "https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=footengo31,footengo01,Footengo69&fields=posts.limit(5){message,created_time,picture}&access_token={your_access_token}";

    $.getJSON(url,function(response){

        var messages = [];

        Object.getOwnPropertyNames(response).forEach(function(page, idx, array) {
            response[page].posts.data.forEach(function(post, idx, array) {
                messages.push(post);
            });
        });

        function compare(a,b) {
          if (a.created_time < b.created_time)
            return -1;
          if (a.created_time > b.created_time)
            return 1;
          return 0;
        }

         //Use jQuery getJSON method to fetch the data from the url and then create our unordered list with the relevant data.
        var html = "<ul>";
            //loop through and within data array's retrieve the message variable.
            $.each(messages.sort(compare), function(i,fb){
                if (typeof fb.picture != "undefined") {
                    html += "<li>" + fb.message + "</br>" + '<img SRC="' + fb.picture + '">' + "</br>" + fb.created_time + "</li></br>";
                }
                else{
                    html += "<li>" + fb.message + "</br>" + fb.created_time + "</li></br>";
                }
            });

        html += "</ul>";

        //A little animation once fetched
        $('.facebookfeed').animate({opacity:0}, 500, function(){
            $('.facebookfeed').html(html);
        });

        $('.facebookfeed').animate({opacity:1}, 500);

    });

}
```

See the working fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/6fhq3dat/2/ (exchange the access token first)...

Comment: Thank you for that, it seems to be exactly what I wanted, but I don't understand how to implement this part `/?ids=footengo31,footengo01,Footengo69&fields=posts.limit(5){message,created_time,picture}`

Comment: Updated. Please have a look at the FB docs next time, it's all documented there.

Comment: Look at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.4#fields and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.4#multirequests and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/url