# Displaying JSON output from API and adding dynamically calculated property to object

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, facebook-graph-api

I'm working on this for about a week and still don't get the hang of it, so maybe you can help me...

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32396326/display-posts-from-multiple-facebook-feed-using-json) I've tried to figure out how to achieve two things:

- **Getting the latest ten points from my facebook feed** (e.g. WIRED) with **GETJSON** and **put them into an object**, which is than **displayed on my website**. [WORKING JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/x0mu3qx2/) (you have to insert an access token first.
- The second thing I'm trying to achieve is where I'm having troubles: I would like to **add a property to each of the fetched posts** which displays a **calculated score for the post** (ideally the sharecount + likescount divided by 2) and sort the posts with the compare function by using this property. 
  I tried to do the following:

```
$.each(messages.attr, function(i,fb){.add('score').attr(fb.shares.count + fb.likes.summary.total_count / 2)
```

I have the feeling that this is terribly wrong, but I really can't find any solution to this...

Thank you,

David

Comment: It's not even valid Javascript syntax. What is `.add('score')` supposed to mean?

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for adding a property to an object is `object.property = value`. So it should be:

```
$.each(messages.attr, function(i,fb){
    fb.score = fb.shares.count + fb.likes.summary.total_count / 2;
});
```

The jQuery `.add()` method is for adding elements to a jQuery collection, and `.attr()` is for setting and getting attributes on DOM elements. They have nothing to do with ordinary Javascript object properties.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your response!

Sorry for not using correct syntax, I'm kind of a newbie in javascript... :-/

I tried to include your suggestions in this new [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/LnnLetgr) however I'm only getting "undefined" as my calculated score... Do you maybe know the reason? Thank you!

Full Code:

```
function fbFetch() {

     var access_token = "CHANGE ME";
  var feeds = "wired"
    var url = "https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=" + feeds + "&fields=posts.limit(10){from,name,message,picture,link,created_time,description,shares,likes.limit(0).summary(true),comments.limit(0).summary(true)}&access_token=" + access_token;

    $.getJSON(url,function(response) {

        var messages = [];

        Object.getOwnPropertyNames(response).forEach(function(page, idx, array) {
            response[page].posts.data.forEach(function(post, idx, array) {
                messages.push(post);
            });


        });

$.each(messages.attr, function(fb, i){
    fb.score = fb.shares.count + fb.likes.summary.total_count / 2;
});


        function compare(a,b) {
          if (a.score < b.score)
            return 1;
          if (a.score > b.score)
            return -1;
          return 0;
        }

         //Use jQuery getJSON method to fetch the data from the url and then create our unordered list with the relevant data.
        var html = "<ul>";
            //loop through and within data array's retrieve the message variable.
            $.each(messages.sort(compare), function(i,fb){
                if (typeof fb.picture != "undefined") {
                    html += "<li>" + fb.message + "</br>" + "Score: "+ fb.score + "</br>"+ "Likes: "+ fb.likes.summary.total_count + "</br>"+ "Shares: "+ fb.shares.count + "</br>"+ '<img SRC="' + fb.picture + '">' + "</br>" + fb.created_time + "</li></br>";
                }
                else{
                    html += "<li>" + fb.message + "</br>" + fb.created_time + "</li></br>";
                }
            });

        html += "</ul>";

        //A little animation once fetched
        $('.facebookfeed').animate({opacity:0}, 500, function(){
            $('.facebookfeed').html(html);
        });

        $('.facebookfeed').animate({opacity:1}, 500);

    });

}

fbFetch();
```